mean cost per game in Guided Cost Learning
In this algorithm, which is an implementation of the paper "Guided Cost Learning: Deep Inverse Optimal Control via Policy Optimization" from Chelsea Finn, Sergey Levine and Pieter Abbeel, why is the mean cost per 1 game increasing instead of decreasing? I've looked for it and i don't really get it.
the cost is computed in this class:
class CostNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(
        self, 
        state_dim,
        hidden_dim1 = 128, 
        out_features = 1, 
    ):
        super(CostNN, self).__init__()
        self.net = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(state_dim, hidden_dim1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(hidden_dim1, out_features),
        )
    def forward(self, x):
        return self.net(x)

Results

but can't figure out if this behavior is a "normal one"

Why should it increase? It could increase or decrease, depending on the vars and values that are being passed to. What vars and values are being passed to?

to me it should be decreasing because the network should learn and optimize the trajectories and so it should improve its precision and so  the mean cost per 1 game should decrease. But instead it keeps increasing. But i must be missing something. The values passed are coming from an "expert" trajectories python file containing a big number of trajectories. In the repo it's the file expert_samples/pg_cartpole.py
